# how to deal with data leakage in historical data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, data-preprocessing, data-leakage

I have a dataset containing matches from 2000 TO 2018 and I am asked to predict match outcomes for the year 2017 to avoid data leakage I am going to just train my model from 2000 to 2016. in the training data do I include 2018 or not?

Answer (score 2):

I just came up with idea that:

1. It’s not realistic to use future data to predict the past. That’s not a real use case.
2. There could be some temporal related changes for players, and sanity wise, using future data can have a latent “in hindsight” effect.